# How to get the RSSI of an AP I'm not connected to?

Tags: networking, wireless

I can get the RSSI of an AP I'm connected to by simply doing:

```
iwconfig wlan0 | grep "Signal level"
```

But how do I get the RSSI of a specific AP that I'm not connected to?

If I do `iwlist wlan0 scan` I get all the AP's and their RSSI, but I can't really grep the RSSI of a specific one that I'm interested in.

Comment: I first interpreted your question that you don't get the signal strength from the `iwlist` output, so I suggested using `aircrack-ng` to scan for devices. But reading it again, it looks like you have the information you want, but only don't know how to extract it from the output? Please clarify if this is true and what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Simply want to get the signal strength for a specific SSID without having to connect to it. I can only use iw or iwconfig/iwlist

Comment: So you're looking for a matching `grep` command that parses the output of `iwlist wlan0 scan` and returns the signal strength of a specified AP? Please add some example output to your question and describe how you want to specify an AP and how your desired result should look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the `grep -Bn` style commands to monitor `rssi` of an AP I'm not connected to, ultimately, some more specific parsers can be written, but this is a good-enough one-liner for a lot of purposes: the output contains the `rssi`

You can use the `scan` options of `iw` or `iwlist` : let's look for an AP called `Sage` that appears in my office space:

```sh
iwconfig # get interface name, let's say it's "wifi0" 
sudo iw wifi0 scan | grep "SSID: Sage$" -B6 # show 6 lines before the SSID
```

output:

```
        freq: 2462
        beacon interval: 100 TUs
        capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0431)
        signal: -79.00 dBm
        last seen: 624 ms ago
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
        SSID: Sage
```

with `iwlist`:

```
sudo iwlist wifi0 scan | grep ESSID:\"Sage\" -B3
```

output:

```
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Sage"
```

I've been using this an either an interactive monitor for signal strength, antenna placement etc using `watch` with this expression, or, for statistics, using `timeout` and `watch`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the aircrack-ng suite to monitor unconnected WiFi access points and their signal strengths.

1. Install the package `aircrack-ng` from the `universe` section of the official Ubuntu repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
   ```
2. Set your WiFi card to monitor mode:

   ```
   sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
   ```
3. Scan for access points and clients in range:

   ```
   sudo airodump-ng mon0
   ```

Example output:

```
CH 13 ][ Elapsed: 32 s ][ 2016-06-17 21:39

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID
 24:65:xx:xx:xx:xx  -59        0     4106  145   1  -1   WPA              <length:  0> 

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe
 24:65:xx:xx:xx:xx  08:D4:xx:xx:xx:xx    0    0e- 0e     0     4101
```

In the first table you see the access points, the signal strength is displayed in the `PWR` column. The second table lists all client devices.

Comment: I'm on an embedded platform with limited tools, just have iwconfig and iw

Answer (score 0):

i am responsing late appologies

you could get the list of network adapters from `ifconfig`
and then `run iwconfig wlp2s0 | grep -i --color Signal Level`

i hope it helps